# convert jsonString contains special characters to jsonObject

Tags: java, json, jsonobjectrequest

I have jsonString which contains special characters.I want to remove these special characters to obtain proper jsonString then jsonObject.
My code is  :

```
String text="\"\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"createdAt\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2023-10-31T11:43:29\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"updatedAt\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2023-10-31T11:43:30\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"createdBy\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":null,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"updatedBy\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":null,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"isDeleted\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":false,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"messageValue\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"name\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"hello world\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"status\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"CREATED\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"priority\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":1\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n}\\\\\\\"\\\"\"";
```

Do you have any idea how can i convert inproper string to proper jsonObject.

I have tried replace all method but I still see some characters :(

What i have done until now:

```
text.replace("\\","").replace("\\n","UUU").replace("\\n",TTT").replace("\"\\\"\\\"\\\"\\\"{","\"{")
```

Comment: How did you how that string?

Comment: It comes from kafka payload request

Comment: This is not compiling. That is, though you have pasted a Java statement, it has some error in the string itself. Can you check and paste the right one? Then something can be done to clean it up into a proper JSON string.

Comment: @SreeKumar I updated my string

Comment: There are 2 double quotes in the beginning. That will not compile. I guess your source of the string is not correct.

Comment: As Sree Kumar said, your code is not valid Java, even after the edit. Besides that, you should pass the string to a JSON decoder, as many times as it has been passed to a JSON encoder. But think about fixing the software (setup) that causes re-encoding a JSON string into a JSON string so many times.

Comment: @SreeKumar I compiled it.It compiles properly now

Comment: If you copied the actual string, the code would have passed the compiler right from the start. So you didn’t copy the actual string but something else, followed by several edits to make it pass the compiler. This makes it even less likely that this is the original string of your problem. But, as said, if you get such matryoshka JSON strings on a repeatedly, fix the software setup instead of trying to convert the string on your own.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing down here only to show how to analyze such issues and design a solution. The solution being presented here is only for the particular string pasted and any that have similar extra characters.

Approach:

1. Study the string to know the included patterns.
2. Create patterns to remove or replace them **in the right order**.

Here is a class that achieves it for the string in question. I have added some comments to explain the approach.

```java
public class SOCleanupJSONString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text="\"\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"createdAt\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2023-10-31T11:43:29\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"updatedAt\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2023-10-31T11:43:30\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"createdBy\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":null,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"updatedBy\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":null,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"isDeleted\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":false,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"messageValue\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"name\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"hello world\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"status\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"CREATED\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"priority\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":1\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n}\\\\\\\"\\\"\"";

        /* 1. Extract the JSON block from the string. 
           NOTE: This pattern is only for object blocks. You may have array blocks as well. Please change this pattern for that. */
        Pattern JSON_BLOCK = Pattern.compile( "\\{.*}" );
        Matcher m = JSON_BLOCK.matcher( text );
        if( m.find() ) {
            text = m.group();
            System.out.println(text);

            /* 2. Un-escape quotes */
            text = text.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"");

            /* 3. Remove (JSON escaped) newline text */
            text = text.replaceAll("\\\\n", "" );

            /* 4. Remove all extra double-slashes.
             *    NOTE: This can be erroneous, if the pattern appears within a value. */
            text = text.replaceAll("\\\\", "" );
            System.out.println(text);
        }
        else System.out.println( "No JSON block found" );

        parse( text );

    }

    private static void parse( String text ){
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            Map map = om.readValue( text, Map.class );
            System.out.println( map );
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Resultant JSON string:

```json
{"createdAt":"2023-10-31T11:43:29","updatedAt":"2023-10-31T11:43:30","createdBy":null,"updatedBy":null,"isDeleted":false,"messageValue":{"name":"hello world","status":"CREATED","priority":1}}
```

Output of `Map.toString()` after unmarshalling the above to a `Map` instance using Jackson:

```
{createdAt=2023-10-31T11:43:29, updatedAt=2023-10-31T11:43:30, createdBy=null, updatedBy=null, isDeleted=false, messageValue={name=hello world, status=CREATED, priority=1}}
```

Comment: If you use an `ObjectMapper` anyway, why not let it do the job instead of an error prone replacement operation, e.g. perform `while(text.startsWith("\"")) text = om.readValue(text, String.class);` right before the `Map map = om.readValue(text, Map.class);`

Comment: @Holger (a) `ObjectMapper` is only an example. The user may use any other tool. (b) Agreed. I am all for avoiding any replacement operation where possible. That is why I specifically mentioned that I am only trying to show a process of analysis-solution and needs to be done in the right way/order.